# Внесение байт в память через регистр Ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, память

В регистре EBX у меня находится адрес на строку в памяти.
Как мне редактировать байты этой строки?
Если я использую mov ebx, 0x73747231, то редактирую байты в EBX, а не в памяти.
В памяти у меня строка "abc2", а нужно чтобы было "str1"
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Используйте EBX как адрес а не как значение, вот такая запись например в одном из вариантов ассемблера `[EBX]` `mov [EBX],0x73747231`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы записать что-либо по адресу хранящемуся в регистре, нужно использовать квадратные скобки (в случае синтаксиса intel):

```
mov [ebx], 's'
mov [ebx+1], 't'
mov [ebx+2], 'r'
mov [ebx+3], '1'
```

Чтобы не повторять инструкции, стоит организовать цикл. Но ещё лучше не изобретать велосипед и использовать специально предназначенные для таких операций инструкции:

```
mov cx, 4
lea di, dststr
lea si, srcstr
rep movsb

dststr db 'abc2', 0
srcstr db 'str1', 0
```